# Why we can not debug the reset or crash issue with JTAG emulator (trace32)?

Tags: c, crash, emulation, jtag, trace32

I have observed reset / crash issue with my target. But when I am trying to debug it with jtag the device doesn't reset or crash. It works correctly. What is happening internally which will not allow the device to reset or crash.

This may be related to hardware dependency. Please sorry if this is not right place to ask this question.

Is there any to debug crash issue with JTAG?

Comment: I don't know about Trace32, but many debuggers clears memory for variables, including the stack used by local variables. This leads to things like pointer being `NULL`. So if your program crashes except in the debugger, it may be a sign of using uninitialized local pointer variables.

Comment: If "without JTAG" means that some cable is physically disconnected, it *could* be that said cable contains a reset signal which is left floating, and thus causing random resets. When hooked up to the JTAG cable the signal is properly pulled high or low, preventing the spurious reset. Worth investigating, at least. I would also recommend checking if the hardware "remembers" causes for resets (embedded processors often do).

Comment: The Trace32 debug solution (Lauterbach) offers a very large set of configuration options, some of which may influence the runtime behaviour. You should check your configuration scripts. Maybe, the support team of the debugger manufacturer can help you out, too.

Comment: There are debugging configuration options that deactivate the watchdogs, or keep them activated but stop the CPU for some time. Please make sure the watchdog is not the cause of your resets.

Comment: I never experienced a hardware glitch similar to letting a reset pin floating with Trace32 and the corresponding adapters (I don't work for Lauterbach but for a company that bought some of their adapters.). I would rather assume a problem in the target board or in front of my keyboard.

Comment: Just saying: Without any further information about your hardware, your software, your boot operation, or any other information when this crash/reset happens it's basically impossible to provide even a guess what the answer might be.